# ASP.NET MVC 3: Helper to turn JavaScript link in to embedded / compressed html markup?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, dotfuscator

Is there a MVC 3 helper that could compress and include linked JavaScript / CSS in the original HTML sent from the server so the client wouldn't have to go get it as a separate request?

We started storing linked images in the cloud while our ASP.NET code is locally hosted.  It allows 100 times the requests but subsequent requests take forever.

We need the first html request to include everything rather than several call backs to the server.  I thought if something existed to identify/compress/dotfuscate JavaScript/CSS in the original HTML sent to the client, it would be much more efficient.  It could be cached too.

Comment: Getting closer to an answer: [Packer](http://svn.offwhite.net/trac/SmallSharpTools.Packer/wiki).  Now just need to make it work as a HTML Helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an answer because in my case, my js was not *linked*. I used a number of helpers to render in script blocks with substuted params for specific on-page tasks. But what I did do was wrap all these helpers thru a common function which in DEBUG just returned the plain script block, but in release, compressed the js string with the [Yui Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: I used conditional directives like you mentioned which was nice to auto determine which ones to use.  Then I found [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) which does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow. That's really all I have to say about that.

Comment: You need to totally add that as your accepted answer so others can find Cassette quicker. Looks like a killer tool.

Comment: Me add it!? :p I haven't used it yet. I plan to tho.